# Can I use the same @property on multiple models in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to define an @property once and use it on two different models.  Is this possible?

Example:

Suppose I have two models, seller and buyer:

```
class seller(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class buyer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And I wish to add a property for the django admin interface to display both models:

```
@property
def display_name(self):
    return f"{first_name} {last_name}"
```

Is there a way to define this property once, but use it for both models?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can define a mixin, that implements this and inherit it on your models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an *abstract* model that can define the `first_name` and `last_name` field as well as the property:

```
class Trader(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @property
    def display_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and then make two concrete models with that:

```
class Buyer(Trader):
    pass

class Seller(Trader):
    pass
```

Here we thus do not only inherit the property, but the model fields as well.

---

If you do not want to inherit the fields, you can implement a mixin, so:

```
class NameMixin:

    @property
    def display_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

and then mix it in the `Buyer` and `Seller` models:

```
class Seller(NameMixin, models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Buyer(NameMixin, models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the mixin option require a new migration?

Comment: @AndrewEinhorn: normally not no, since this is only mixing in a property, the model itself does not change, we do not create additional fields, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
class Base(models.Model): # Make it abstract to avoide repeating code
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @property
    def display_name(self):
       return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    class Meta:
          abstract = True
```

Then Inherit from it like this:

```
class seller(Base):
      pass

class buyer(Base):
      pass
```